# ng-include with $state.go() from ui-router not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have this:

```
<ng-include src="'app/components/widgets/buttonbar.html'"></ng-include>
```

That includes buttons from both the /customers route and the /customers/:id routes.  I can dynamically add buttons with actions.  When I'm going to customers I add buttons using this service interface:

```
  this.buttons = []
  this.addButton = function(id, title, classes, href, action, sortOrder){
    console.log(this.buttons)
    var button = {};
    var pushViable = true;
    button.id = id
    button.title = title
    button.classes = classes
    button.href = href
    button.action = action
    button.sortOrder = sortOrder
    angular.forEach(this.buttons, function(index, sort){
      if(button.sortOrder === sort){
        toastr.error('Button Sort Order Exists')
        pushViable = false;
      }
    })
    if(pushViable === true){
      this.buttons.push(button)
      this.buttons = sortButtons(this.buttons)
      $rootScope.$broadcast('buttonBar:update')
    }
  }
```

like so from my customerlist:

```
buttonSvc.addButton('newCustomer','New Customer', 'button small', '#','newCustomer()',0)

$scope.newCustomer = function(){
  var customerModal = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'app/customers/newCustomer.html',
    controller: 'customerModalCtrl',
    windowClass: 'small'
  })

  customerModal.result.then(function(){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('customer:update')
  })
}
```

(doing so from a modal works with ui-foundation from pineconellc on github)

```
  buttonSvc.addButton('goBack','Go Back', 'button small', '#','toTheGrid()',2)
```

This button, however doesn't work, with this code in effect:

```
  $scope.toTheGrid = function(){
    $state.go('customers.list')
  }
```

If I just make a regular button and use the function it works fine.  So I've got an issue.

As I have now placed a bounty, if you would like to see more code, please ask and I will post relevant sources.

Comment: Can't see the picture, can you provide also the other source code involved in this matter? Thanks

Comment: [Here is a link](https://gist.github.com/dkran/b530625ee18bc8706106) to a gist containing my buttonbar service controller and template that I'm interacting with.  I may add some other stuff in a sec. Thanks.

Comment: It seems you're passing the function here as a string `buttonSvc.addButton('goBack','Go Back', 'button small', '#','toTheGrid()',2)` can you remove the single-quote surrounding the `toTheGrid()` function and try it again? If still doesn't work try removing also the parenthesis `()`. Then let me know what happened. Thanks

Comment: I've given you much more code to look at including routes.  Please note:  The call from customerList.js works perfect, with parens inside a string.  the call from customerDetail.js fails.  I've included my route definition file and both of those files in completion.

Comment: But that solution didn't work.  the implementation expects a function with parens inside a string.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. So you aren't even getting in the function with the generated button? Could you post the HTML of what the generated button looks like compared to the one that you hard-coded?

Comment: `<button class="button small ng-scope ng-click-active" ng-click="toTheGrid()">Go Back</button>`  Is the static button vs `<a href="#" class="button small ng-click-active" ng-click="toTheGrid()">Go Back</a>` is the dynamic.

Comment: I think I'm running into the core of the issue.  Unless the parent controller contains the function, I can't run it outside of the current ui-view even in this manner.  I tried changing the /customers to abstract as per my gist, and now none of them work, which would be the expected behavior if that were the case.  I may have to abandon it and just use dynamic dom elements everywhere.  Unless you have a solution here, I may answer the question after I tinker more.

Comment: hi @dkran are you able to post the code in plunkr ? Thx

Comment: I'm not very familiar, maybe I could mock up some sort of example tomorrow. I think it would need heavy refactoring

Comment: You might be better off changing the implementation of button bar to broadcast an message instead of directly calling a function.

Comment: Where does your code fail? Are you able to enter `toTheGrid` clicking on the button?

Comment: I'm able to enter toTheGrid by clicking on the static button I create (i.e. `<button ng-click="toTheGrid()">go back</button>` the dynamic one fails, even though the html is near identical.  The dynamic one just has the scope falling on the li component outside of it, it seems.  At this point I unfortunately don't have it in my code right now, but there is more than enough code to reproduce it there and I'm still looking for a solution.  If anyone is familiar with plunkr I'll tinker with them to get it working.  PS look at my gist in the third comment or so.

Comment: scope inherit issue? you can check your code and follow scope inherit;not sure , need more your code.

Answer (score 1):

Look at two buttons:

```
<button ng-click="foo()">click</button>
<button ng-click="{{'foo()'}}">click</button>
```

first work, second not. (Generated html is the same)
See plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/znFa6lGUGmQ0bYw097zH?p=preview
And reason is simple - in 2nd case, 'foo()' is considered just as basic string.

So just modify your code to pass function to addButton.

Comment: I did try that, but the issue is the controller for the button, as per https://gist.github.com/dkran/b530625ee18bc8706106 the gist, is outside the scope of the button's function.  I was trying to pass the function to the service to then get it to run in a separate controller.  can it be done?  When you look at the rendered html, it's not a string literal.  It's an actual ng-click="toTheGrid()" that's being rendered.  there's no string issue being the problem here.

Comment: Do not rely on what you see in html - i.e. go to browser console and edit html button - remove ng-click from it. Button will still work. Thats because directive ng-click is already executed and click event is binded to certain js function. You can pass string and then in directive/controller make function from it if u want, like $parse(functionName)($scope, params).

Comment: This might be something similar to what I'm trying to do.  I don't have the code in my codebase anymore, but I was essentially trying to push the function outside of it's current ui-view to add it to the button-bar to get it to go back.  so it was a scope issue of sorts where it could no longer access the function from within the ui-view of the customerDetail.js controller - The parse documentation is practically nil.  What does it do?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are passing `'toTheGrid()'` as a string instead of a function.
I would try something different like this:

**buttonbar.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="button-group" ng-controller="buttonBar">
    <li ng-repeat="button in buttons track by button.sortOrder">
      <a href="{{button.href}}" class="{{button.classes}}" ng-click="button.action()">{{button.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**customerDetail.js**

```
buttonSvc.addButton('goBack','Go Back', 'button small', '#', $scope.toTheGrid, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice from the comment, you said you had a dynamic html tag as follow:

```
<a href="#" class="button small ng-click-active" ng-click="toTheGrid()">Go Back</a>
```

I think the href may prevent the ng-click from firing up. You can try dropping the href="#" out of the anchor tag (by default, it will call preventDefault). Or you can write a custom directive for attribute on anchor tag, and in the custom directive, call preventDefault() on the click event

Comment: Or you can take the ng-click out, replace href by ui-sref="customers.list"

Comment: might have been one of the easiest bandaids to the immediate problem, but it wouldn't have solved what I was actually trying to do with the code.

Comment: So the ui-sref works for you, right? Did you try to take out href from <a> tag to see if the ng-click fires up? Or write an attribute directive for anchor tag?